# Maven Javadoc Plugin During Site Goal: javadoc: error - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Please increase memory

Tags: maven-3, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have been struggling to increase the memory of my javadoc plugin via my pom file.  For some reason my Mac build slave fails during the *site* goal with an *OutOfMemoryError*.  I tried adjusting the *maxmemory* of the javadoc plugin via my *pluginManagement* section of the pom (as per the [maven-javadoc-plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#maxmemory)):

```
...
<build>
  ...
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <maxmemory>512m</maxmemory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  <pluginManagement>
  ...
</build>
...
```

This didn't seem to help anything, my build still failed with an out of memory error.

So I decided to put this directly in my plugin declaration instead (see the *build-plugins-plugin* section below:

```
...
<build>
  ...
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <maxmemory>512m</maxmemory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
...
```

...and yet this is still not working, the Mac build slave still fails during the site goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was being an idiot.  The *site* goal uses the plugin defintions declared in the reporting section of the pom.  Therefore I had to add my max memory configuration here instead, see below:

```
...
<build>
  ...
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  <pluginManagement>
  ...
</build>
...
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <maxmemory>512m</maxmemory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
...
```

Based on this result, it is my assumption that Maven will not pick up configuration details defined in the *build-pluginManagement* section of the pom for plugins defined in the *reporting* section.  Cheers.

Comment: Turns out reporting plugins DO NOT pick up version information from the build-pluginManagement section.  I just noticed some warnings at the start of my mvn execution.

Comment: And let me complicate things further...I was using the maven-release-plugin's perform goal to deploy my released project to our repository.  When it came to running the javadoc plugin, I was again getting out of memory errors.  To fix it in this case, I actually had to increase the memory in the <build><plugins><plugin><configuration> tag.  Sheesh...confusing right.